# Requested URL was not found on this server while running a laravel application

Tags: php, linux, laravel, ubuntu

I am facing an issue with deploying my Laravel 5.3 application.

I get an error saying my route was not found on the server. Surprisingly, i am able to get to the welcome page without a problem but if I try to click on the registration button or any other route, I get this error.

I'm using a linux 16.04 server on digital ocean and everything is working fine on localhost. I have tries multiple solutions but nothing seems to work. Any help is much appreciated.

**My Routes File**

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('login');
})->name('login');

Route::get('/login', function () {
    return view('login');
});

Route::get('auth/{provider}', 'Auth\RegisterController@redirectToProvider')->name('auth');
Route::get('auth/{provider}/callback', 'Auth\RegisterController@handleProviderCallback');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function(){

    //Tasks
    Route::get('/task', 'TaskController@index');
    Route::get('/task/{taskId}/{notification?}', 'TaskController@view');
    Route::get('/create-task', 'TaskController@create');
    Route::get('/close-task/{taskId}', 'TaskController@finaliseTask');
    Route::post('/reinitialise-task/{taskId}', 'TaskController@reinitialiseTask');

    Route::post('/task', 'TaskController@store');
    Route::post('/task/comment/{taskId}', 'TaskController@postTaskComment');

    //Reports
    Route::get('/reports', 'ReportsController@view');
    Route::get('/create-report/task/{taskId?}', 'ReportsController@generateReport');

    //Settings  
    Route::get('/settings', 'SettingsController@index');
    Route::post('/category', 'SettingsController@storeTaskCategory');

});
```

I am able to access the login route but cant access any other.

I have setup my virtual host as shown below.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerAdmin info@myemail.com
ServerName mydomain.name.com
ServerAlias www.mydomain.name.com
DocumentRoot /var/wwww/html/public
ErrorLod ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${Apache_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

<VirtualHost>
```

I also would love a solution that doesn't force me to move files around as doing so end up breaking composer and artisan.

Comment: What the `APP_URL` in your `.env` and `app.php` inside config folder?

Comment: Is `mod_rewrite` installed? You can check with `apachectl -M`

Comment: `AllowOverride all` for your laravel, Put this into your web server configuration inside virtualhost definition

Comment: try clearing cache on server. php artisan route:clear

Comment: @HendraNucleo APP_URL is mydomain.name.com

Comment: @JeremyHarris I cant see mod_rewrite if I run that command. How do I install it?

Answer (score 1):

For your .htaccess to take over and handle routing through Laravel, you need to tell your vhost to allow it's config to be overridden (by the .htaccess file).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName mysite.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/mysite/public"

    <Directory "/var/www/mysite/public">

        Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted

        # ADD THIS IF USING PHP-FPM
        <FilesMatch "\.php$">
            Require all granted
            SetHandler proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000
        </FilesMatch>

    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

The `AllowOverride All` value tells Apache that it is ok for the application to modify the vhost config.

If you don't see `mod_rewrite` in the [output of `apachectl -M`](https://superuser.com/questions/284898/how-to-check-which-apache-modules-are-enabled-installed), you need to enable it:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Make sure after making any of these changes that you reload Apache:

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Comment: This is proven concept. +1.

Comment: I have followed these steps and now I cant get to mydomain.name.com.It also throws a similar error now.

Comment: You tagged this Ubuntu and `a2enmod` is a command you should be able to run if you have Apache installed on Ubuntu. That error is common if running CentOS/RedHat. Are you certain `apachectl -M | grep rewrite` doesn't come back with anything?

Comment: Remove the PHP-FPM part inside the directory section if you aren't using PHP-FPM.

Comment: Did you reload Apache? `sudo service apache2 reload`. Also, what errors are you seeing?

Comment: The requested URL / was not found on this server. that's the error I'm seeing. Yes, I reloaded my apache and even restarted it.

Comment: Sounds like maybe your `.htaccess` file is missing from your **public** folder or is configured incorrectly. Is this what you have? https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.3/public/.htaccess

Comment: It is exactly the same. letter for letter.

Comment: Your original vhost has `DocumentRoot /var/wwww/html/public` -- with four w's instead of 3. Try changing that to match the correct folder.

Comment: that was just a typo here. I wasn't sure how Id copy and paste quickly using nano so I just typed it in.

Comment: I will need to see your actual vhost then, otherwise I am out of ideas. You can highlight in many modern terminals and when you let go of your mouse button it automatically copies to the clipboard -- try that.